# Maven 3.0.3 package is not working

Tags: maven-3

Hi I have a `mvn` sub module whose sole purpose is to collect jar's from various other module and create a zip file with all dependencies and configurations.

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <version>0.1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>dist</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>dist</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate zip</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Now if I use `mvn assembly:assembly` it creates the desired `zip` file. But if I use `mvn package` it doesn't do any thing i.e. its not creating the zip file. Just gives below output and finishes.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dist 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.120s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 15 16:34:09 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/92M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea on why this is not working. What is that I am missing here.
Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: I don't know what mvn package is supposed to do. Do you?

Comment: `package` - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR. (Copied from [mvn site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Packaging) :-) )

Comment: Fair enough, so what is "not working"? (My point was to be more specific in the question. :P)

Comment: @icedwater `mvn package` command is not building zip file. It just finishes without doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert mentioned you have to move out your plugin from plugin-management. Try something like this

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <descriptors>
                  <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>generate zip</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

That's not how pluginManagement works. You should define at least as a standard build-plugin.
During a lifecycle, Maven will use its default and it goes through the build-plugins to see if there's a plugin bound to a phase. If it finds a plugin, it will look at the pluginManagement for the same plugin to see if there are some additional configurations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I am new to maven I am not sure how to do it, so it would be more helpful if you can give a short example as to what should i change.